# What is the best way to wrap `purchaserInfo` for easy comparisons throughout your code using RevenueCat

Tags: swift, in-app-purchase, revenuecat

What would be the best way to wrap `Purchases.shared.purchaserInfo` to just return `true` or `false` when doing multiple comparisons in an `If` statement.

What I want to be able to do is to quickly check if the user has access to PRO features by having a method or a property that return true or false since I need to make multiple checks in an if statement, something like... `if userHasAccess && someOtherCheck { // do something}`

Is this a valid solution?

### Singleton Class:

```
    class IAPHelper {

        static let shared = IAPHelper()

        func hasAccessToProFeatures()->Bool{
            var hasAccess:Bool?
            Purchases.shared.purchaserInfo { (purchaserInfo, error) in
                if let purchaserInfo = purchaserInfo {
                    if purchaserInfo.activeEntitlements.contains("myEntitlement") {
                        hasAccess = true
                    }else{
                        hasAccess = false
                    }
                }
            }
            return hasAccess!
        }
    }
```

### Usage:

```
    if IAPHelper.shared.hasAccessToProFeatures() && someOtherCheck{
        // unlock PRO features
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Shared instances are not bad, however for such a small class you could declare `hasAccessToProFeatures` as a static variable instead.

```
class IAPHelper {

static var hasAccessToProFeatures: Bool {

    var hasAccess:Bool?
    Purchases.shared.purchaserInfo { (purchaserInfo, error) in
        if let purchaserInfo = purchaserInfo {
            if purchaserInfo.activeEntitlements.contains("myEntitlement") {
                hasAccess = true
            }else{
                hasAccess = false
            }
        }
    }

    guard let isProMember = hasAccess else {
        return false
    }

    return isProMember

  }

}
```

Then you could call it like:

```
if IAPHelper.hasAccessToProFeatures && someOtherCheck {
    // unlock PRO features
}
```

Comment: @ Barnyard - I like your approach, but I think the `else` clause in `if purchaserInfo.activeEntitlements.contains("myEntitlement")` is redundant and can be removed since the `guard let` is taking care of that, right?

Comment: You are right, guard will take care of instances where the `hasAccess` is false.

Comment: You could also replace the guard and current return statement with `return hasAccess ?? false`.